# ng-route get parameters from url

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I faced an issue while getting param using ng-route 
where param value contain '==' that is remove from URL

> index.html#/app/test?param=value==

when use $state.params.param
i suppose the result should be 'value==' but it is actual return 'value'

Comment: try to encode the value first: `index.html#/app/test?param=value=%3D`

Comment: @plonknimbuzz the value come from other system i don't have access to this URL

Comment: Your param must be  URL encoded. The problem is depending on the other system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is a bug on angular 1.3

> Solve :  I upgrade to 1.6

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this below code.....

```
GetEmployeId : function () {//this function will get the last value of current page url.
        var urlPath = $window.location.href;
        var result = String(urlPath).split("/"); //will split the url by forword slash
        if (result != null && result.length > 0) {
           var id = result[result.length - 1]; //will get the last value from url.
            return id;
        }
    },
```

See [here](http://dotnetdetail.com/complete-crud-operations-using-angularjs-and-asp-net-mvc5/#Step%20#%207) the complete article.